# How to grant dependent lib in jnlp file all permissions?

Tags: java, security, permissions, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a serious problem with Java Web Start that I can't get my head around. The situation is the following: I have a JavaFX app, written Java8, that I want to deploy using Java WebStart. Until recently I used HTTP for communications with a server, and everthing worked fine. I could deploy the app using Web Start embedded in the browser or as a standalone app.

However I have now changed the communication to use WebSockets. For this I am currently using the tyrus implementation. And now comes the problem: Since I have added the tyrus lib, I always get an AccessControlException when tyrus tries to access a system property:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "weblogic.websocket.client.max-aio-threads" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer.openClientSocket(JdkClientContainer.java:106) ~[na:na]
```

However I can easily access exactly this property from any of my own classes, e.g. if I do this

```
logger.info(System.setProperty(ClientManager.WLS_MAX_THREADS, "1"));
logger.info(System.getProperty(ClientManager.WLS_MAX_THREADS));
```

I get the expected result with no security problems.

Of course I have made sure that all jars are fully signed, all jars have the `Permissions: all-permissions` flag in their Manifest.MF files, and the jnlp does have the required `<security><all-permissions /></security>` tag.

Apart from this I also tried using the jetty websocket implementation, however this gave me exactly the same problems.

So does anybody have an idea why the tyrus code is not able to access the same system property as the main code?

Comment: There are system properties to set debug trace on the access controller (forget what they are off hand). Setting global state within a shared VM is a bad idea (obviously). Some instances are forbidden unless the process is unshared. (Oh, and signed doesn't necessarily mean fully trusted.)

Comment: I just tried this and it (a JavaFX application using Tyrus web socket client libraries running under Web Start) worked fine for me (see [github project](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test)).  I used the JavaFX maven plugin to build and (self-)sign the app and required jars with all permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the help, I finally found the answer. The hint by @Tom Hawtin gave me the right clue, I still need to wrap the call to `webSocket.connectToClient()` in `AccessController.doPrivileged()` to get full rights in the dependent code.

However I still don't fully understand why signed code with `Permissions: all-permissions` is not trusted, maybe I should read up on the WebStart security model.

Edit:
Ok, after playing around much more and finding more weird bugs I found the real problem: When I integrated the WebSockets into the application I made heavy use of the `CompleableFuture.xxxAsync()` methods. And by default those are running on the common ForkJoinPool, which in turn run on special threads (`InnocuousForkJoinWorkerThread`) if a security manager is present (as is obvious the case using jnpl). And those don't have any permissions whatsoever, which correctly triggered all those errors.

So the solution is to use a custom Executor for the `xxxAsync(xxx, executor)` calls.

Comment: I don't understand this answer either because my test application worked without wrapping calls inside doPrivileged.  Glad you got it working though.

Comment: I think the method you are using is [`ClientManager::connectToServer(...)`](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.9/org/glassfish/tyrus/client/ClientManager.html#connectToServer(javax.websocket.Endpoint,%20javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig,%20java.net.URI)) not `connectToClient()` (which I can't seem to find a reference to anywhere)?

Comment: @jewelsea Of course you are right, connectToServer() is the correct method name

Comment: @jewelsea post1: What JDK did you use for your test application? I'm using idk 8_u25 and just realized that maybe Oracle increased the security once again without telling anyone about what they changed...

Comment: I was using Java 8u20 (on OS X), but I upgraded to Java 8u25 to check just in case anything changed there, however the application still worked fine for me after the Java 8u25 upgrade.  You can checkout the project I linked in my earlier comment on your question in case you want to try it on your system.