# java 8 jnlp asynchronous calls and permissions

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, jnlp

I have a simple jnlp application that demonstrate java 8 asynchronous calls, and accessing privilege data, eg System.getProperties(). I have given it full permission in the jnlp file, and the code is correctly signed with a proper CA Root certificate, but the code still throws an exception. I cannot find anything that could explain or resolve this problem, and as far as I know, all permissions required has been granted. Can anyone help?

The code:

```
package com.text;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class LambaTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CompletableFuture<String> test = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
        try {
                System.out.println("Asynchronous Thread");
                Properties properties = System.getProperties();
                System.out.println("https.protocols="+properties.get("https.protocols"));
                System.out.println("Asynchronous Thread successful");
                return "Hello";
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Asynchronous Thread FAILED");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });

        test.thenAccept(string -> {
            System.out.println("Priting String within async call " + string);
        });

        try{
            System.out.println("Main Thread");
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            System.out.println("https.protocols="+properties.get("https.protocols"));
            System.out.println("Main Thread successful");
        } catch (Exception er) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread FAILED");
            er.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the jnlp descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
  codebase="http://localhost/"
  href="test_uat.jnlp"
>
<information>
  <title>TEST - uat</title>
  <vendor>TESTing service</vendor>
  <homepage href="http://localhost/" />
  <description>JNLP Test scripts</description>
  <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.8+" />
  <jar href="Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.test.LambaTest">
    <argument>empty</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

And this is the console output:

```
Asynchronous Thread
Asynchronous Thread FAILED
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.LambaTest.lambda$main$0(LambaTest.java:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Priting String within async call null
Main Thread
https.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
Main Thread successful
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grant dependent lib in jnlp file all permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231276/how-to-grant-dependent-lib-in-jnlp-file-all-permissions)

Comment: According to the above question, it seems you need to use a custom executor, as the common forkjoin pool runs in a restricted context that does not have the permissions to read the properties.

Comment: Now that I correctly understand my problem, and the answer given by Holger, it is a duplicate of [How to grant dependent lib in jnlp file all permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231276/how-to-grant-dependent-lib-in-jnlp-file-all-permissions). However I still feel Holger's answer was better, in that he gave a specific solution to a specific case. This could serve as a specific example of the general solution described in the duplicate.

Comment: Indeed, some duplicates are good to keep around as they present a different view on the problem and sometimes also its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ordinary execution, a method’s permissions are the intersection of the permissions of all methods on the current call stack.

So if the thread pool calling your code has less permissions than your code or even no permissions at all, your code has less or even no permissions in that call context.

This ensures that an unprivileged method can not simply perform a privileged action by calling an unaware privileged method. It’s the responsibility of the privileged method to verify the arguments of the caller, perform its own security check if the action is considered security relevant, and then calling [`AccessController.doPrivileged(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged-java.security.PrivilegedAction-) explicitly to declare that the indirect caller’s privileges should not be considered. If that does not happen, the unprivileged caller still can not abuse the method to elevate its rights.

```
public class LambdaTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CompletableFuture<String> test = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Asynchronous Thread");
            PrivilegedAction<Properties> action = System::getProperties;
            Properties properties = AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
            System.out.println("https.protocols="+properties.get("https.protocols"));
            return "hello";
        }).whenComplete((string, throwable) -> {
            if(throwable != null) {
                System.err.println("async action failed");
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
            else System.out.println("Async call returned " + string);
        });

        try{
            System.out.println("Main Thread");
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            System.out.println("https.protocols="+properties.get("https.protocols"));
            System.out.println("Main Thread successful");
        } catch (Exception er) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread FAILED");
            er.printStackTrace();
        }
        test.join();
    }
}
```

By the way, when you wan to get a single property, you should use `System.getProperty(String)` instead. As [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--) states:

> Note that even if the security manager does not permit the `getProperties` operation, it may choose to permit the `getProperty(String)` operation.